# Can't install "CiviCRM UK GiftAid"

Tags: extension, gift-aid-extension

Getting the following error when installing this extension. Had to enable PHP errors to get this as without all I see is a 500 server error w nothing in the Apache2 logs.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in /var/www/website.vhost/web/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.giftaid-3.0.1/CRM/Civigiftaid/Utils/Contribution.php on line 99
```

Answer (score 4):

Ah, v3 of this extension is incompatible with PHP7: https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.giftaid/issues/49

Comment: That sounds like a bug and it is probably worth the report the bug at the extension github. And if you are a developer probably fix the bug. Or fund a developer to fix the bug for you.

Answer (score 3):

The developers are in the process of fixing this: see

https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.giftaid/issues/49

So it will probably be fixed in the next release. If you need to install it sooner, here's how. Find your extension directory (go to **Administer->SystemSettings->Directories** and you will find the path in there. The abbreviation `[civicrm.files]` usually refers to `sites/default/files/civicrm`). IN your SSH or FTP environment, navigate to there and then open `uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.giftaid/CRM/Civigiftaid/Utils/Contribution.php` for editing. Find every line like this:

```
$batchContribution =& new CRM_Batch_DAO_EntityBatch();
```

In each case, delete the line and replace it with these two lines:

```
$entityBatch = new CRM_Batch_DAO_EntityBatch();
$batchContribution =& $entityBatch;
```

This does not change what the code does but it just changes the syntax to make it compatible with PHP7.

Comment: I have done as you suggested above, but with no luck.
When I try to install, I get the following error.. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in /homepages/21/d758583217/htdocs/health-e-learning/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.giftaid/CRM/Civigiftaid/Utils/Contribution.php on line 99 (If I have the Mailchimp Extension enabled, this gives an error too!) It would be great to know how to repair the damage if I can't use the Extension! Trying to install this extension has also damaged my frontpage too, it no longer looks the way it used too! Please help!

Comment: Well, if you can't use the extension, just disable it; you should not have to repair anything. Also, if you have followed my answer then I don't see how you are getting that error. Can you post what line 99 of that file actually says? Ta.